# How can I access the data in custom toolbar for admin-on-rest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, admin-on-rest

I use admin-on-rest. I made a custom toolbar for the user data edit page. How inside this toolbar to get access to user data?

Comment: Please add some code that you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use redux-form [selectors](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/selectors.md/) to retrieve either the full form or only some fields.

For that, you'll have to make your custom toolbar a connected component using redux `connect` and call the selectors from your `mapStateToProps` function.